# Convert all files of .flac format found in any sub-directory of main directory to .mp3

Tags: bash, sh

I have the following problem: Imagine you have a directory named "Music" and inside there, in various sub-directories, there are files ending in .flac.
I want to write a bash script that finds all these files and for each one
converts in the same directory that it was found, a .mp3 file and (optionally) if this file is created correctly to delete the original .flac file.

I tried the following code, which I constructed by collecting bits and pieces from various places, which I leave as a more formal indication of what I want to achieve:

```
#!/bin/bash

find ./Music -type f -name "*.flac" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' a; do
    echo "converting file: $a"

    # Get File name
    FN=`echo $a | sed 's/.\{5\}$//'`

    # Convert to mp3
    ffmpeg -i "$FN.flac" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -y "$FN.mp3"

    # If converted correctly delete
    if [ -f "$FN.mp3" ]; then
        echo "done"
        rm "$a"
    fi 
done
```

Use of ffmpeg is optional (but preferred).
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
find ./Music -type f -name "*.flac" -execdir sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -y "${1%.flac}.mp3" && rm "$1"' Cvt {} \;
```

#### How it works

1. `find ./Music -type f -name "*.flac"`

   Search for regular files (`-type f`) under directory `./Music` whose names end with `.flac`.
2. `-execdir sh -c '...' Cvt {} \;`

   For those files, start a shell and run the commands in quotes.  The name of the flac file is provided to the shell script as argument 1: `$1`.

   `Cvt` is assigned to `$0` which you will see should the shell script generate errors.

   The shell script consists of:

   - `ffmpeg -i "$1" -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 -y "${1%.flac}.mp3"`

     Run the `ffmpeg` command that you found.
   - `&&`

     Proceed to the following command only if the preceeding command succeeded (error code=0).
   - `rm "$1"`

     Erase the original flac file.